# simplifying multiple variable assignment code

Tags: c#, .net, minify

How should I reduce the amount of code I must write to perform this?

I really don't have a single clue what technique should I use.

```
test1.Content = "test1...";
test2.Content = "test2...";
test3.Content = "test3...";
test4.Content = "test4...";
test5.Content = "test5...";
test6.Content = "test6...";
test7.Content = "test7...";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "minify"?  The only minification I see possible is removing linebreaks/whitespace and changing variable names (if you can).  Why do you want to minify anways?  Minification is for reducing network traffic - C# code is rarely transferred over the network in an application.

Comment: do you mean refactor?

Comment: do you want to reduce the amount of code you are typing?

Comment: Well I thought about reducing amount of code.

Comment: `test4.Content = "test45...";` might be problematic

Comment: @NadiaKrawczyk "I thought about reducing amount of code" for what goal?  performance?  It won't be any faster.  Readability? Maintenance?  It would also help to know what `test1` is.  Some sore of control?

Comment: well yes it's control (in this particular case textbox) and in wpf you use 'content' instead of 'text'. I wanted to reduce it in order to improve readability.

Comment: well yes it's control (in this particular case label). I wanted to reduce it in order to improve readability.

Comment: @DStanley In reality, it might even [be slower...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a dictionary to store your variables instead of defining all of them with named variables.

```
var testDic = new Dictionary<int, Test>();
for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
{
    testDic[i] = new Test() { Content = "test" + i + "..." };
}
```

and then access them like `testDic[2]` or `testDic[6]`.

Comment: I'm confused; why not an array? `Test[]` Or even a List `List<Test>`.

Comment: Both of them are possible options too. @Tobi